# Python Program not Working, and Python IDLE Doesn't Hi-Light the Errors

Tags: python, hex, calculator

So I like to program, and love hexadecimal; I am working on a calculator in python that converts hexadecimal to decimal, does the desired operation in decimal, then converts the answer to hexadecimal. The program isn't working, the standard python IDLE (the one that comes standard when you install python) says there is a syntax error, but instead of hi-lighting where the error is like normal, it just says "invalid syntax" when I press the "F5" key (which runs the program), and then opens the shell. I entered the program line by line in the shell, and is somewhere inside the `def ansDef(oper):` function.
Here is the code:

```
print("Valid operations: +, -, *, /, ^, rt")
numA = input("Enter first number: ")
oper = input("Enter operation: ")
numB = input("Enter second number: ")
baseA = int(numA, 16)
baseB = int(numB, 16)
numBRT = float(1) / float(baseNumB)
def ansDef(oper):
    return{
        "+":
            baseAns == float(baseA) + float(baseB)
        "-":
            baseAns == float(baseA) - float(baseB)
        "*":
            baseAns == float(baseA) * float(baseB)
        "/":
            baseAns == float(baseA) / float(baseB)
        "^":
            baseAns == float(baseA) ** float(baseB)
        "rt":
            baseAns == float(baseA) ** float(numBRT)
    }.get(oper, return{
            print("ERROR: INVALID OPERATION")
        })
ans = hex(baseAns)
print(ans)
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement as part of an argument to `dict.get()`. That's wrong.

Comment: After you resolve that, you have to actually call that function instead of assuming it's called automatically and then trying to refer to its local variables. I'd say it's back to the drawing board (or the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html)).

Comment: The problem is that your dict items need to end with commas. Change `baseAns == float(baseA) + float(baseB)` to `baseAns == float(baseA) + float(baseB),` (note comma at end) ... and etc for all of the items in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your code as an example for `Python` syntax， it is really worth to read the [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) or [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) **official tutorial** once.

```
print("Valid operations: +, -, *, /, ^, rt")
numA = input("Enter first number: ")
oper = input("Enter operation: ")
numB = input("Enter second number: ")
baseA = int(numA, 16)
baseB = int(numB, 16)

def ansDef(oper, a, b):
    if oper == "+":
        return a + b
    elif oper == "-":
        return a - b
    elif oper == "*":
        return a * b
    elif oper == "/":
        return a / b
    elif oper == "^":
        return a ** b
    elif oper == "rt":
        return a ** 1.0 / b
    else:
        raise Exception("ERROR: INVALID OPERATION")

try:
    baseAns = ansDef(oper, float(baseA), float(baseB))
    ans = hex(int(baseAns))
    print(ans)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I will not use your suggestions. I hate exceptions and find them annoying. Here is a github link for the final program that works: https://github.com/5b-name-5d/Python-Programs/blob/Hexadecimal-Calculator/HexCalculator.py